# Create Youtube "like" button for specific video with API v3.0

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

There's a website that offers exactly what I need:
https://likebtn.com/en/youtube-like-button

Except, it's a 3rd party service. I've seen some examples of creating something like it yourself but all those examples used the Youtube v2.0 API.

I'm creating a website that acts as an extension of my Youtube channel (http://www.lepel.tv) and I'd like to offer as much functions as Youtube itself offers.

Does anyone know how to create a "like" button for a specific video (based on videoID) using the v3.0 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [`rate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) endpoint of their API.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want!

Comment: After doing a bit more reading, I see I need to use OAuth to validate a user, which will ask the user for permission to manage their account for them. Is there no way of achieving this with a simple API key?